# problems with saving state - react-draggable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted save state after refresh page i made handling function but it is looking like state doesnt want to save what should I do to make it correct?

```
const DraggedItem = () => {

const [x, setX] = useState(0);
const [y, setY] = useState(0);

const handleStop = (e, data) => {
    setX(data.x)
    setY(data.y)
  }

return(
 <Draggable defaultPosition={{x: x, y: y}}  onStop={handleStop}><div>drag me here</div></Draggable>
)

}
```

Comment: Probably, you won't be able to do that without using `cookie` for example, because every time you refresh page `useState` always will be set to default, so, there is no opportunity to make 'remember' it

Comment: how about local storage is it possible to save it in local storage?

Comment: It's a little bit difficult to say that without any tests, but you can try, sounds like it's gonna work - so, why not

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using local storage in order to persist your data during page refresh.

**Something Like This:**

```
const DraggedItem = () => {

    const [x, setX] = useState(0);
    const [y, setY] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
       setX(localStorage.getItem('x-position'));
       setY(localStorage.getItem('y-position');
    },[]);

    useEffect(() => {
       localStorage.setItem('x-position', data.x);
       localStorage.setItem('y-position', data.y);
    },[x,y]);

    const handleStop = (e, data) => {
        setX(data.x);
        setY(data.y);
    }

     return(
       <Draggable defaultPosition={{x: x, y: x}} onStop={handleStop}> 
       <div>drag me here</div></Draggable>
     )
}
```

Not the best solution and is somewhat anti-pattern but hopefully, it gets you somewhere.